# Two problems on topological properties of two different sets

Tags: general-topology

> Which properties hold for the following sets?
>   Open, connected, closed, nowhere dense?
>
> 1. $$A =\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=mx\}\setminus \{(0,0)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$$
> 2. $A$ is the closure in $C[0,1]$ of the set $B$ where
>      $$B:=\{f\in C^1[0,1]: |f(x)|\leqslant 1\mbox{ and }|f’(x)|\leqslant 1,\, \forall x\in[0,1]\}.$$

---

For (1) the straight line but origin missing. So it only nowhere dense. Am I right?

For (2) I have no idea. also guide me for few resoureces where I can find the different topological properties of the given set.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For (2), you need to use Ascoli-Arzelà theorem. (1) is correct.

Comment: will you explain please

Comment: You should be clear about what you need explained.

Comment: There is not much to be said that is not written [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).